# Problem setting content control with OpenXML SDK 2.0

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I have a Word 2007 doc with content control, title and tag set to "Control1" and the value "X". I am trying to change the value of Control1 to "Y"

```
  string sdtName = "Control1";
  SdtBlock sdt = mainPart.Document.Descendants<SdtBlock>()
            .Where(s =>
            s.GetFirstChild<SdtProperties>().GetFirstChild<Alias>().Val.Value
            .Equals(sdtName)).First();

  Response.Write(sdt.InnerXml);
  //results in X
  sdt.InnerXml = "Y";
```

X is displayed correctly, but when the InnerXml is set to "Y" it results in X being deleted from the document

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You're directly setting InnerXml so "X" is getting overwritten. Are you trying to rename the "Control1" alias to "Y" or are you trying to change the value of "X" to "Y"?

Comment: I was trying to change the value of "X" to "Y"